# Export to excel from xlsm template

Tags: c#, windows, epplus

**Requirement**

---

I need to create a windows application in C# where the output is an excel file (xlsm) which is created from a template in xlsm format (contains macros).

In the template file, "IneTemplate.xlsm" there is a hidden sheet, "Data". I have to fill the sheet with data (no headings for the columns. only data) from database and save using a Save File Dialog.

---

**What I done so far ?**

---

I have a button. In the Button click I wrote this.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //Default filename for new excel
                    String newFileName = string.Concat("ExcelExport", '(',
                                   DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
                                   .Replace(':', '_')
                                   .Replace('/', '-')
                                   .Replace(' ', '_'), ')', ".xlsm");

                    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\App_Data\IneTemplate.xlsm");

                    if (existingFile.Exists)
                    {

                        using (var MyExcel = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
                        {
                            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = MyExcel.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"]; 
                            int tripCount = 1;

                            //I have few trip data in a checked list box which I need to fill in the first column (column "A")
                            foreach (object item in clbTrip.CheckedItems)
                            {
                                DropDown trip = (DropDown)item;
                                worksheet.Cells[tripCount, 1].Value = trip.Value;
                                tripCount++;
                            }

                            int stopcount = 2;
                            int rowCount = 1;

                            //I have to fill the remaining columns with stops from each Trip in each column.(stops from Trip1 in column "B", from Trip 2 in "C" and so on) 
                            foreach (object item in clbTrip.CheckedItems)
                            {
                                DropDown trip = (DropDown)item;

                                //Get the stops in a Trip from database
                                DataSet dsStopNames = objTrip.GetStopNames(trip.Id);
                                foreach (DataRow row in dsStopNames.Tables[0].Rows)
                                {
                                    worksheet.Cells[rowCount, stopcount].Value = Convert.ToString(row["StopAliasName"]);
                                    rowCount++;
                                }
                                stopcount++;
                                rowCount = 1;
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                //Create a save file Dialog
                                SaveFileDialog saveFileDialogExcel = new SaveFileDialog();
                                saveFileDialogExcel.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsm)|*.xlsm";
                                saveFileDialogExcel.Title = "Export Excel File To";
                                saveFileDialogExcel.FileName = newFileName;

                                if (saveFileDialogExcel.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                                {
                                    if (saveFileDialogExcel.FileName != "")
                                    {
                                        string path = saveFileDialogExcel.FileName;
                                        MyExcel.SaveAs(ms);
                                        File.WriteAllBytes(path, ms.ToArray());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured While Saving , Check Whether the file is open");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

---

**Other Info**

---

1. Used [EPPlus](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fepplus.codeplex.com%2F&ei=VvsIVbmcI4SHO5edgEA&usg=AFQjCNF_t5PnGk4iAy_newrisHbIGiSKQQ&bvm=bv.88198703,d.d2s) for excel generation.
2. There is no Microsoft Office installed in the system.

---

**Problem**

---

A file got created. But when I open, Its shows file is not in proper format or corrupted or something.

---

Is there any other way to achieve this?
Will EPPlus able to handle xlsm files?

Please Help.

Comment: So have you got the solution for this using EPPLUS

Comment: Yes. I created a new xlsm file(i think the file i used as template is not working. so i create a new xlsm file from scratch) and EPPlus successfully generated xlsm file from the template file. Macros working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Actually I must have to fill provided serff template and I have got the solution